How do I integrate the Maxwell-Boltzmann-Distribution in terms of the 4-velocity?
I want to calculate the interaction rate of a 2->2 process where the distribution function of the particles is given by the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. The result has already been published in the paper by Gelmini and Gondolo, and I am currently looking at the following paper to understand it: https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07659 (from page 7). However, I would like to be able to calculate it myself and don't understand two points:

How do we arrive at the following equation:
$$ 
\frac{d^3p_1}{2E_1}\frac{d^3p_2}{2E_2} = 2^4d^4pd^4k\delta((p+k)^2-m^2)\delta((p-k)^2-m^2)
$$
With $p = (p_1+p_2)/2, k= (p_1-p_2)/2$. Especially since on the left side there's integration over three dimensions, while on the right side it's taken over four dimensions.

On page 8 of the linked paper, the interaction rate for low temperatures is calculated (Equation 30). I understood it as implying that the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution can be used instead of the Bose-Einstein distribution. However, when I substitute this, I get the modified Bessel function of the second kind instead of the first kind—which makes sense to me, because the integral contains $sinh(x)^2$ and not $cosh(x)$. Can someone explain why the Bessel function of the first kind is used?


Edit
In case there are people wondering about the same integral: If I haven't made a mistake, it can be easily solved using integration by parts.
$$
\int^\infty_0 \sinh(x)^2e^{-a\cosh{x}} dx \\
= \int^\infty_0 (-a^{-1}\sinh{x})(-a\sinh{x})e^{-a\cosh{x}} dx \\
= [-a^{-1}\sinh{x}e^{-a\cosh{x}}]^\infty_0+a^{-1}\int^\infty_0 \cosh{x} e^{-a\cosh{x}} dx \\
= a^{-1}K_1(a)
$$

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Are you familiar with the relativistic equivalent of Maxwell-Boltzmann?

@LucaD For 1. see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/810929

Thank you, that was both really helpful! But there's still something I don't quite understand from the other post: Why does the first equation, where 1/2E is represented as an integral, hold true? If I take the integral, as I understand it, the Delta distribution should only ensure that pp has no spatial component (assuming pp represents a 4-vector), and the Heaviside function should only ensure that p^0 is greater than zero . So where does the 1/E dependence come from? I hope it's okay that I'm commenting here—I can't leave comments on other posts yet; otherwise, I'd ask there.

@LucaD  $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty ! dp^0 \theta(p^0) \delta((p^0)^2-\vec{p}^2-m^2)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty ! dp^0 \theta(p^0) \delta(p^0-\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2})/ \lvert 2 p^0 \rvert$ $ = 1/(2 \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}) =1/(2 E(\vec{p})$). Remark: the second zero at $p^0=-E(\vec{p})$ does not contribute because of $\theta(p^0)$.
